# GridView Items Width

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1, winrt-xaml, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

Got a GridView that its items width are set by the first one width(Screenshot)

How could I set some auto width for each item?

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind PopularItems}" Style="{StaticResource GVStyle}" Height="230">
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="GVTemp" x:DataType="models:LessDetails">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Height="180" Width="132" Source="{x:Bind Img}" />
            <TextBlock Margin="4,4,0,4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Center"
       Text="{x:Bind Name}" Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

[image: Width of items set by the first item]

Comment: It seems to me that in your scenario you already know what your desired width is (the width of the image plus something). Maybe you can consider explicitly setting the width you want in the data template and let the text wrap. That's not generally a good option but in your case it might do. Otherwise Jeffrey Chen's solution is the best, create your own ItemsControl. See [this](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/sloscialo/windows-8-gridview-and-variable-sized-items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not auto-width each item in a GridView control, it is by designed to use the first item's size as the uniform size (ListViewItemPresenter for each items has the same size).

For the auto-size scenario, I suggest you using the StackPanel or creating a custom ItemsControl.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ItemsStackPanel:

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

The only downside is that it doesn't wrap items.. For that you can use the `ItemsWrapGrid` but then you lose the auto-width functionality (first item determines the width of all items).

There's also the `VariableSizedWrapGrid` that can be used by giving items a certain ColumnSpan/RowSpan, but it's not quite the same as automatically calculating the width.

If you want the best of both world, probably you'll need to write your own custom panel.

**UPDATE:** For a solution that allows for both automatic width and item wrapping, you can use the [`WrapPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/wrappanel) control from the [UWP Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/).